# how to show dropdown box after selecting any one of checkbox created in loop angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, checkboxlist

I am new to angular js programming so please excuse me if my question is naive.
I am populating a list of checkboxes depending upon values inside a json object.
I am using ng-repeat to iterate through the list of keys & values received & display the check box. When each of the check box is clicked I am making a server call to get relevant data. The data I receive should be populated in a dropdown list only when it is clicked & the dropdown should disappear on un-click. I want to capture the dropdown selected option after the user selects it.
I am stuck as to how to get it.

My code for reference :

HTML :

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="OptionsController" >
       <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in options" ng-if="value === 'text'">
    <!--         {{key}} : {{value}}-->
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="getDistinct(key)"/>
                <label>{{key}}
            </label>
        <div class="animate-show">
        <select  id="selector" ng-model="QueryFormData.Graph.selected">
            <option ng-repeat="name in QueryFormData.Graph.options" 
                    ng-value="name">{{name}}</option> 
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Controller code :

```js
myApp.controller('OptionsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'datashare',
  function($scope, $http, $location, datashare) {
    //$scope.options = datashare.jsonData;
    $scope.options = {
      "_id": "571a0fcfaa6d92581ec99b2e",
      "Name": "text",
      "isstring": "text",
      "value1": "number",
      "value": "number",
      "status": "text",
      "ItantaTime": "time"
    };
    $scope.keyArr = [];
    $scope.QueryFormData = {
      Graph: {
        options: [
          'Line Graph'
        ],
        selected: 'Line Graph'
      },
      displayValue: ''
    };
    $scope.getDistinct = function(key) {
      if ($scope.keyArr.indexOf(key) == -1) {
        $scope.keyArr.push(key);
        var ServerAddr = "http://localhost:2000/getDistinct/" + key;
        console.log("Server Addr :" + ServerAddr);
        $http.get(ServerAddr, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          })
          .success(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
          })
          .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log(data)
          });
      }
      console.log("changed : " + key);
    };
  }
]);
```

With current code I am seeing all the dropdowns at once. I want to show the dropdowns as a toggle functionality on check box selection.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `ng-if`.  Use the built-in filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in options" ng-if="value === 'text'">
```

Can be

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in options | filter: { value: 'text' }">
```

For your filtering problem, you can again use the `filter` in `select` elements to only get the dropdown values you want.  Your `JSON` response must have a filterable property though...  So, please post your `JSON`.

You use it like this:

```
<select ng-options="item.key as item.name for item in collection| filter:{ someProperty: true }">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have made use of the filter option instead of ng-if. The JSON Object i receive as part of GetDistinct call from the server is of the format {"value":[ '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ]}. I want to show a drop down consisting of the values received above. I am still confused about how would it result in me showing the dropdown in toggle mode. My problem is I am unable to show the dropdown list corresponding to the check box which is selected.

Comment: The link [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)  says that **The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and will throw if used with one.**